Functional Analysis multi option question.
Consider the sequence of continuous linear operators $T_n : l^2 \to l^2$ defined by $$ T(x)= ( 0,0,\cdots ,0, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, x_{n+3}, \cdots )$$ for every $x= (x_1, x_2, \cdots )\in l^2$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, for every $x\neq 0$ in $l^2$
$A$. Both $\|T_n\|$ and $\| T_n(x)\|$ converge to $0$.
$B$. Neither  $\|T_n\|$ nor  $\|T_n(x)\|$ converges to $0$.
$C$.  $\|T_n\|$ converges to $0$  but not $\|T_n(x)\|$ .
$D$.  $\| T_n(x)\|$ converge to $0$ but not $\|T_n \|$.
According to me last option $D$ is correct as $\|T_n\| =1$ for all $n$ and $\| T(x) \| = (\sum_{k= n+1}^{\infty } |x_{k}^2|)^{\frac{1}{2}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (tail of convergent sequence). Please check and advise me . Thank you.

Yes, your reasoning is right.

@JulioPuerta Thank you.......

It looks right to me, but you could elaborate a bit more on your claims.
To show that $\lVert T_n\rVert=1$ for all $n$, note firstthat if $\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\in\ell^2$ is such that $\lVert\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=1$, then
$$\lVert T_n\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\lvert x_j\rvert^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lvert x_j\rvert^2}=\lVert\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=1,$$
so $\lVert T_n\rVert\leq1$, and furthermore this is attained, as if we take $\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\in\ell^2$ with $\lVert\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=1$ and set
$$y^{(n)}_j=\begin{cases}
x_{j-n},&j>n,\\
0,&\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
then
$$\lVert T_n\{y^{(n)}_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\lvert y_n\rvert^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lvert x_n\rvert^2}=\lVert\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\rVert=1.$$
This shows that $\lVert T_n\rVert=1$ for all $n$.
Your argument for why $\lVert T_n(x)\rVert\to0$ as $j\to\infty$ for all $x\in\ell^2$ looks good to me, as you're just using a basic property of convergent series.

Thank you..........
